# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[n -> n -> n -> n -> n]

Tags: angular, typescript, micro-frontend

Does anyone have any idea what the 'n' over here signifies? However I don't have any service called 'n' in my entire codebase. Following is the error snippet that I am getting.

```
main.js:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[n -> n -> n -> n -> n]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
at S0.get (main.js:1:828027)
at Dg.get (main.js:1:830707)
at Dg.get (main.js:1:830707)
at Dg.get (main.js:1:830707)
at Rb (main.js:1:815915)
at Be (main.js:1:816016)
at n.ɵfac [as factory] (main.js:1:1353968)
at Dg.hydrate (main.js:1:832095)
at Dg.get (main.js:1:830659)
at Dg.get (main.js:1:830707)
```

Angular version - 14.2.11

Node version - 14.21.1

**How am I getting this error?**

I am using Angular elements to create a microapp.
I am using this code to register the custom HTML tag 'my-widget' and loading the component 'myComponent'.
`ngDoBootstrap() { const myMicroElement = createCustomElement(myComponent, { injector: this.injector }); customElements.define('my-widget', myMicroElement); }`
'myComponent' has many dependencies in it and and has child components as well. When I am trying to
access it from here its throwing the above error.

I tried the following fixes but none worked for me,

- Added the missing services in providers of app.module.ts.
- Tried to access 'myComponent' from routes.

Comment: You're proving us prod logs. Can you run your app in dev mode ? You'll have the correct symbols.

Comment: Ok let me try it. Thanks